next.js pages router with next-intl - is it possible to localize pathnames?
I have next.js v13.3.1 with Pages Router.
I'm trying to set up localized pathnames with next-intl
I've added createLocalizedPathnamesNavigation and createMiddleware that shares the config
https://next-intl-docs.vercel.app/docs/routing/navigation
https://next-intl-docs.vercel.app/docs/routing/middleware
also added request.ts file with getRequestConfig but it does not seem to be called at any point
// in next.config added
const withNextIntl = require('next-intl/plugin')();
module.exports = withNextIntl(nextConfig);

added NextIntlClientProvider in the _app.tsx

At first I was hitting a redirect loop of next-intl middleware and saw a warning during compilation:

next-intl has found an i18n config in your next.config.js. This likely causes conflicts and should therefore be removed if you use the App Router.
If you're in progress of migrating from the pages folder, you can refer to this example: https://next-intl-docs.vercel.app/examples#app-router-migration

so i removed the i18 from there.
Now I'm stuck getting an error from next-intl useRouter: Unknown locale encountered: "en-GB"
And looking at https://next-intl-docs.vercel.app/docs/getting-started/pages-router they say to set up i18n routing in next.config, which I just removed because of the warning and redirect loop. I noticed the warning mentiones App Router
Question: is the localized pathnames feature supposed to work with Pages Router?
